# Generating map between frame number and frame sample time using SampleGrabber filter in directshow

Tags: directshow

In one of my application I need to know the map between frame position (frame number)  and actual frame sample time for a given video file.
I'm using Directshow SampleGrabber filter in callback mode. I'm overriding BufferCB method of ISampleGraberCB class, whenever the callback is called, I'm mapping the arrived sampletime to frame position in a map. Frame position is incremented whenever a new sample arrives starting from zero.
Though I'm able to generate the required map, the above approach is very slow when it comes to handle  large video files.
Can someone provide any suggestion on how to quickly generate this map or any other better approach.

Thanks in advance.

Pradeep

Comment: why do you need to generate such a map? why not just "videolength / sampletime" to get the framenumber? Without decoding the frames your approach should be fast enough. Do you have an example what "slow" means.

Comment: I want to play whole file frame by frame and also I want to provide random, backward and forward seeking. The grabbed frame is converted into opencv image and then forward to user interface. So I decided to keep a map of frame number and timestamp. For a file above 6000 frames it is taking around 30second. I need to reduce it as much as I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically no such thing as "frame number" in DirectShow, only time stamps. The only thing to do the needed is to go through the entire file and record timestamps, as you already do.

However, the process might be *way* faster if you set the sample grabber to receive raw/undecoded fames. This way there is no need for decoder and the whole iteration through frames happens pretty quick. Don't forget to remove clock from the graph to request ASAP processing (as opposed to default real time pace).

Comment: I actually set sync source to false. But still it takes time. For 6000 frames it is taking 30sec and for frame above 100,000 takes above 2mins. I want to reduce it as much as I can. I'll try to explore the option of just just receiving raw. I hope it works. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I just want to how can I configure sample grabber for raw frame. I've following filter graph. Source Filter->Sample Grabber->Null Renderer. I'm configuring media type to video and subtype to RGB24. Pretty much same as explain in msdn example. I think the decoder are loaded automatically when I run the graph. How can I configure it to get just raw video?

Comment: Initializing to RGB24 will make decoder appear, just do video without any subtype. You can always review the graph you have to see if there is anything "unexpected" added to the graph, what you don't really expect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I was able to suppress the loading of decoder. The mapping time has reduced a lot. But once I got the mapping I want resume my normal decoding of the frames. I tried but setting media type of SampleGrabber back to RGB24 and rerun the graph. It didn't work I'm getting grabage frames. Do I need release the graph and rebuild it for RGB24 video subtype to come into effect. Even the decoders are not loaded.

Comment: Yes you need another graph with decoder to play this back. You actually can have two graphs together, one for playback, the other just for qucik-mapping frames. They should not interfere one with the other taking data from the same file.

Comment: Unfortunately time stamp mapping using just raw video frames doesn't seem to work with all video format :(. Specifically file encoded with divx5, MPEG Video and strangely WMV3. So I guess it will be selective based on codec.

Comment: 1. For some of the files like MPEG Visual and WM3. The callback getting called just once so map not generated.
2. For  some avi file, when no decoder is used sample time starts with 0, however when decoder is used it startes with actual sample time which shifts the whole map by one. This is found in the files encoded with divx5.