# SampleGrabber callback is getting called spuriously even when graph is paused

Tags: directshow

I'm using Directshow SampleGrabber in callback mode to capture video frame from source file and do some processing. Also I would like to maintain the current playback rate of video and need to support both random, forward and backward seeking. For this I'm also doing some local buffering in a different thread.
I'm running graph with syn source set to NULL, so as to get maximum speed. However when I pause the graph after fixed amount of buffering. The SampleGrabber callback is getting called spuriously even when graph is paused. This is affecting my frame indexing and tracking. I want to resume the graph exactly from the same position at which it was paused. However if I run the graph with default clock it works fine but then my playback get affected. I want buffering thread to finish as soon as possible.
How can I make sure that callback is not called when graph is paused? Any thoughts or suggestion would be of great help.

Thanks in advance
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

Paused graph typically has all the same streaming internally (active state) with the exception that renderers are blocking streaming, esp. as soon as enough data is received for a preview banner. Since you removed clock from the graph, your renderer is likely to not block execution because it does not hold any clock to pause against. [In your case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898471/generating-map-between-frame-number-and-frame-sample-time-using-samplegrabber-fi) this is the problem coming out of your intent to reuse the same graph for quick parsing through file and playback. Separate graph design looks having more chances to do better.

Comment: I think two graphs method should do well. I have implemented first graph without clock to generate time stamp. And second for playback. I'll try to disable clock in this one and see if it works. Thanks Roman for suggestion.